# How to calculate ${\rm Pr}(F_A|F_B)$ or ${\rm Pr}(F_A| F_B, F_C, F_D)$ in a four node network?

Tags: probability, correlation, self-study

I have just started learning these things, and I would really appreciate any help on this.
There are 4 nodes in a network (say $A,B,C,D$), and each node has certain failure probabilities, namely ${\rm Pr}(F_A)$, ${\rm Pr}(F_B)$, ${\rm Pr}(F_C)$, ${\rm Pr}(F_D)$.
Then, I have a $4 \times 4$ correlation Matrix which contains the correlation coefficients for every pair of nodes.

**How can I calculate ${\rm Pr}(F_A|F_B)$ or ${\rm Pr}(F_A| F_B, F_C, F_D)$?**

Answer (score 2):

Since this a self-study question, I will provide some hints that will hopefully be usefull.

1. Use a more useful notation (in my opinion). For each node $k \in \{A, B, C, D \}$, let $I_k$ be a binary random variable indicating failure, that is
   $$
   I_k = 
   \begin{cases}
   1, & \text{if the node $k$ is a failure},\\
   0, & \text{if the node $k$ is a failure}\\
   \end{cases}
   $$
   and let $p_k = {\rm Pr}(I_k = 1)$ denote the probability of failure of node $k$.
2. Compute ${\rm corr} (I_k, I_j)$ to see the information that is provided in the correlation matrix.
3. Compute ${\rm Pr}(I_A = 1 | I_B = 1)$ using the definition of conditional probability, $$ {\rm Pr}(I_A = 1 | I_B = 1) = \frac{{\rm Pr}(I_A = 1, I_B = 1)}{{\rm Pr}(I_B = 1)}, $$ and point 2.
4. To come

Comment: I did think along similar lines to your steps 1 and 2. But I wasn't sure that it was possible to recover $\rm{Pr}(F_i\cap F_j)$ from the correlation. I can now see that it is, using $\rm{Cov}(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$, and the formulas for expectation and standard deviation of a [Bernoulli random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) => +1 / deleted my answer.